# Is it risky to use both Fedora and Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, fedora

Since I have two computers I would like to run both under the two biggest linux distribution.

If I develop apps on one, will it corrupt stuff on other computer (assuming every programming folders are synced)?

Programs can involve compiled stuff (C and Java mainly) and the use of libraries (OpenGL for example).

Comment: Why should they do that? At worst, binaries compiled on the one they won't run on the other if they use different and incompatible libraries; and that's not really likely for your average program.

Comment: Please describe what you mean by "everything is synced".

Comment: @Kusalananda think of something similar to Dropbox

Comment: @Maxim Yeah? And when you say "everything", do you mean you're syncing things like `/usr/lib` and `/bin`?

Comment: Obviously not, just the code and its executable

Comment: Obviously? The question is unclear as it does not mention exactly what is being synced. It is still unclear even if taking your last comment into regard as it refers to "some code and its executable". Is this a private project or some base system code and executable? This matters.  Please [edit] your question and describe exactly what it is you are syncing.

Comment: syncing code ? welcome `git`

Comment: I use Syncthing because I also apply on medias (but that is not at all important for the question)

Comment: IMO you'd be better off picking one of them as your main OS and installing that on both computers.  You will not easily be able to run binaries compiled on one OS on the other - libraries, versions, and other things will differ too much.   If you find you need to use the other OS (or just want to learn or play with it), then install it in a VM on one or both of the computers.  I recommend Ubuntu as your primary OS.

Answer (score 4):

I maintain a few pieces of software on a diverse collection of Unix systems, both on various Linuxes and on BSD. I "sync" the code (but not the binaries) by means of `git`.

As long as your two machines are of the same hardware architecture and as long as the needed shared libraries are installed on both Linux systems (with correct versions), you should expect the compiled code to *probably* work. If it doesn't, it won't "corrupt stuff", it will just refuse to run.  Compiling the code into *static* binaries will make them more likely to run on the two machines.

[As cas points out in comments](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/428088/is-it-risky-to-use-both-fedora-and-ubuntu/428122?noredirect=1#comment772759_428122), there *could* be instances where a program runs but misbehaves due to other environmental differences.

I tend to recompile my applications separately on each system though, as I can't generally expect the versions of shared libraries to be the same everywhere, and also since I my systems are completely different Unices.

Comment: Sometimes a program compiled on a different environment won't refuse to run but will run incorrectly because of subtle incompatibilities.  This can be far worse than just refusing to run.

Comment: @cas Good point.